# If a cyclotomic integer has (rational) prime norm, is it a prime element?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Let $p$ be a rational prime. Consider the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p] $ of the $p$-th cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. If the norm $N(\alpha)$ of $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$ is a rational prime, must $\alpha$ be a prime element of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p] $?

If it helps, I only need the case where $N(\alpha) \equiv 1$ mod $p$.

Comment: This is true in any number ring; it follows painlessly from the unique decomposition in prime ideals, but a direct proof without ideals is a bit tough.

Comment: Yes it means it is a prime element. And for showing $(\alpha)$ is a prime ideal, you need to show that $|N(x)|$ extends to an integer-valued (multiplicative) [norm on ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_norm)

Comment: Thank you! If either of you would write it up as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [user1952009](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276986/user1952009), we can look at the norm of the ideal $(\alpha) \subset \Bbb Z[\zeta_n]$.

**Definition.**
Let $K$ be a number field and let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of $\mathcal O_K$. Then the *(absolute) norm* of $I$ is defined as the cardinality of the quotient ring $\mathcal O_K / I$, which is [finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486591).

**Proposition.** Let $x \in \mathcal O_K$ be non-zero. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735863)
$$N( x\mathcal O_K) = |N_{K/\Bbb Q}(x)|$$

---

Finally, if $\alpha$ has a prime norm, then the ideal $(\alpha)$ has a prime absolute norm, say $p$, which means that the ring $\mathcal O_K/(\alpha)$ has $p$ elements. It [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110062) that this ring is the field $\Bbb F_p$ (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043373)), and $(\alpha)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_K$ and $\alpha$ is prime in $\mathcal O_K$.