# Using totally ramified prime to find the degree of extension of cyclotomic field.

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Let $K\subset L$ be number fields. A prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is totally ramified in $\mathcal{O}_L$ (or in $L$) iff $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L = \mathfrak{P}^n$, $n=[L:K]$.

> Suppose $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ where $\zeta_m =
>  e^{2\pi i/m}$. Show that $[L:K]=\varphi(m)$ using the following two facts:
>
> 1. if $m=p^k$, then $p\mathcal{O}_L = \langle 1-\zeta_m\rangle^{\varphi(m)}$.
> 2. if $\mathfrak{p}$ is totally ramified in $L$ and unramified in another extension $L'$ of $K$ , then $L\cap L'=K$.

My idea:

*Firstly, prove that $\langle 1-\zeta_m\rangle$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_L$. Then we will have a totally ramified prime, and use this to somehow show that the degree of extension for $m=p^k$ is indeed $\varphi(m)$. Then somehow use the second fact to prove for all $m$.*

However, the only way I could prove that $\langle 1-\zeta_m\rangle$ is a prime ideal is by using (1) [if an ideal has a prime norm, then it is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2074572/); and (2) norm of a principal ideal is equal to the norm of its generator. But this involves computing norm of  $1-\zeta_m$, which requires the knowledge of the degree of extension (number of embeddings or minimal polynomial). Hence it will be a circular argument.

I have spent a full day thinking about this problem and am still clueless. I would be grateful if someone could provide hints/outline of the solution.

**Edit:**
I was able to use the first fact and prove for the special case that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^k}):\mathbb{Q}]=\varphi(p^k)$. However, now I don't know how to extend it to the general case using the second fact.

Comment: As far as I understand, the exercise is not asking you to prove 1) and 2), it's asking you to assume 1) and 2) to be true and use them to prove the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m = p^k > 2$ and $\zeta = \exp(2\pi i/p^k)$, the only prime that ramifies in $L = \mathbb Q(\zeta)$ is $p$. This is because the discriminant of $L$ is of the form $\pm p^a$, and ramified primes are those dividing the discriminant. You may compute this discriminant using the integral basis $1, \zeta, \ldots, \zeta^{p^k-1}$ for $\mathcal O_L = \mathbb Z[\zeta]$, and the formula
$$
\operatorname{disc} O_L 
= \prod_{i < j} (\zeta^i - \zeta^j)^2
= \pm N_{L/\mathbb Q} (\Phi_{p^k}'(\zeta) ).
$$
For more details, see page 96 of Milne's [notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf).

Your statement 2 then implies the desired result, by using the fact that $$\mathbb Q(\zeta_m) \cap \mathbb Q(\zeta_n) = \mathbb Q(\zeta_{\gcd(m,n)}) = \mathbb Q$$ for $m$ and $n$ relatively prime, and using the multiplicativity of $\varphi$.